# Spring Boot Actuator paths not enabled by default?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

While updating my Spring Boot application to the latest build snapshot and I am seeing that none of the actuator endpoints are enabled by default. If I specify them to be enabled in `application.properties`, they show up.

1) Is this behavior intended? I tried searching for an issue to explain it but couldn't find one. Could somebody link me to the issue / documentation?

2) Is there a way to enable all the actuator endpoints? I often find myself using them during development and would rather not maintain a list of them inside my properties file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two parts to this answer:

> "Is there a way to enable all the actuator endpoints?"

Add this property `endpoints.enabled=true` rather than enabling them individually with `endpoints.info.enabled=true`, `endpoints.beans.enabled=true` etc

**Update:** for Spring Boot 2.x the relevant property is:

```
endpoints.default.web.enabled=true
```

> "Is this behavior intended?"

Probably not. Sounds like you might have spotted an issue with the latest milestone. If you have a reproducible issue with a Spring Boot milestone then [Spring's advice](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot#reporting-issues) is ...

> **Reporting Issues**
>
> Spring Boot uses GitHub’s integrated issue tracking system to record bugs and feature requests. If you want to raise an issue, please follow the recommendations below:
>
> Before you log a bug, please [search the issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/search?type=Issues) to see if someone has already reported the problem.
>
> If the issue doesn’t already exist, [create a new issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new).

Comment: I figured as much. I created the issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1033.

Comment: Seems I had some outdated version which was before the the `/info` and `/status` were default enabled. Everything works after updating. Though you should update your answer to include the correct property `endpoints.default.web.enabled` and I will accept it.

Comment: @Adam I've updated the answer: "Update: for Spring Boot 2.x the relevant property is: `endpoints.default.web.enabled=true`".

Comment: How to set this in intellij?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: use this only in dev environment, not in production!

> Is there a way to enable all the actuator endpoints?

Using Spring Boot 2.2.2 Release, this worked for me:

On the file src/main/resources/application.properties add this:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

To check enabled endpoints go to http://localhost:8080/actuator

Source: [docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints)

Comment: Please note that using this code snippet will expose all endpoints on the REST interface. This includes endpoints that will allow other people to read your environment variables or dump the heap of your application, which will be a significant security risk for your application (stealing credentials or even gaining remote code executing and hijacking your server). Spring generally recommends against exposing all endpoints like this - if, for some reason, you want to do it, make sure that you strictly limit who can access it.

Comment: @malexmave thanks, a little bit late, but I updated my answer to clarify that this shouldn't be used in production environments.

Answer (score 0):

Even if we enable all the actuator endpoints as below
`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` (In case of YAML the star character should be surrounded by double quotes as "*" because star is one of the special characters in YAML syntax)

The `httptrace` actuator endpoint will still not be enabled in web by default. HttpTraceRepository interface need to be implemented to enable httptrace (See [Actuator default endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints), [Actuator endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints/), [Actuator httptrace](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-http-tracing/)).

```
@Component
public class CustomHttpTraceRepository implements HttpTraceRepository {

    AtomicReference<HttpTrace> lastTrace = new AtomicReference<>();

    @Override
    public List<HttpTrace> findAll() {
        return Collections.singletonList(lastTrace.get());
    }

    @Override
    public void add(HttpTrace trace) {
        if ("GET".equals(trace.getRequest().getMethod())) {
            lastTrace.set(trace);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the endpoints can be accessed using the url,

```
http://localhost:port/actuator/respective-actuator-endpoint
```

(Example http://localhost:8081/actuator/httptrace)

If there is a `management.servlet.context-path` value present in properties file then the URL will be,

```
http://localhost:port/<servlet-context-path>/respective-actuator-endpoint
```

(Example http://localhost:8081/management-servlet-context-path-value/httptrace)

Comment: Please note that exposing all endpoints on the REST interface is quite dangerous. They include endpoints that will allow other people to read your environment variables or dump the heap of your application, which will be a significant security risk for your application (stealing credentials or even gaining remote code executing and hijacking your server). Spring generally recommends against exposing all endpoints like this - if, for some reason, you want to do it, make sure that you strictly limit who can access it.